# Google Analytics with local Django Application

Tags: django, google-analytics

I am trying to add Google Analytics (GA) to my Django application and I am a beginner to Django. My application is not deployed to the internet, i.e. I access it through http://127.0.0.1:8000/. According to this tutorial https://pypi.org/project/django-google-analytics-app/, I need a **tracking code** which I cannot get because GA does not accept http://127.0.0.1:8000/ as a website URL. How can I add GA to my local Django app and get the related analytics on GA. Thanks a lot for your help!